# Initialize Google Mobile Ads SDK (Admob) only once?

Tags: java, android, admob

if we need to initialise Admob SDK then should we initialise it for once at MainActivity.class or  there's need to initialise it in every activity in which Admob Ads are present?

As per this link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start  "To initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK at app launch, call MobileAds.initialize() in the onCreate() method of the MainActivity class."

So should we call it only once for every Ads in different activity?

Comment: You should probably call it within only the Activities that have ads

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your app only needs to call that method once, typically at startup in the first activity. There's no need to call it twice during a single execution of the app, or in every single activity.

See the [official reference docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds.html#initialize(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) for details.

Comment: Google AdMob: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

AdMob with Firebse: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Answer (score 12):

The best place to initialize the Ads SDK is from the `onCreate` method of your Application. If you don't have an Application class yet, I recommend your create one.

Answer (score 0):

Add your AdMob App ID to your app's AndroidManifest.xml file by adding the  tag shown below. You can find your App ID in the AdMob UI. For android:value insert your own AdMob App ID in quotes, as shown below.

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" 
            android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>

Then add 
MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");

Refer to official developers.android.com reference 
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: This does not answer the question.